# Multiple rows to one comma-separated value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

We want to display multiple column value into the single column with comma separated value
below is the my table data

[image]

Below is the SQL query i am trying:

```
    select 
         name,
         STUFF((SELECT '; ' + facilty FROM leads Name FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') 
 as facilty,
         address
    from leads
```

Query Result

[image]

Now when I execute the query in SQL Server, I want reuslt to be like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use where clause :

```
select name , STUFF((SELECT '; ' + facilty 
                     FROM leads  
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                    ),1,2,'') as facilty, address 
from leads
where name is not null;
```

Comment: this working fine i know. is not null condition is working  but i want some other method to do this

Answer (score 2):

Use `string_agg()`:

```
select max(name), string_agg(facility, ','), max(address)
from leads
group by leadid;
```

Comment: Would be helpful to mention that `STRING_AGG` is supported only if you are using SQL Server version 2017 and higher

Comment: @PriyankPanchal . . . It was released three years ago and isn't even the current version.